# Error when opening an XPage - cannot load document

Tags: xpages

Am coming across an intermittent problem when opening an Xpage. I have a button on a dialog to open another XPage in a new browser window, the code in the button is

```
var path = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
var xpage = "Claim.xsp"
var fullpath = path + "/" + xpage;
var url = fullpath + "?action=openDocument&documentId="+ Action.claimDocID
view.postScript("window.open('" + url + "')"
```

(if anyone has another way instead of the view.postScript let me know, just couldn't figure out how to open in a new browser window)

Occasionally when the window opens I'll get an error - Could not open document, below is the entry in the log.

05/04/2017 08:26:10 AM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Could not open the document. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
05/04/2017 08:26:10 AM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document

CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Could not open the document    com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:529) at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148) at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100) at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474) at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:165) at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576) at com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.publishControlData(UIViewRootEx.java:1288) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.initBeforeContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1615) at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.init

<-- is from the error-log-0.xml

BUT, when I press reload on the browser the page loads, so the URL is correct. I placed all sorts of print statements on the XPage, in the Java managed bean it also uses, and when the error occurs nothing is printed. The error is immediate, whereas when reloading it takes time and the messages are printed. After the first error, it doesn't occur again.

A couple of other things about this application, it is password protected, it is running on HTTPS. The XPage it loads does have a Notes document that's located in another database plus it uses a Managed bean. If anyone has any ideas be grateful.

Thanks

Cameron

Answer (score 0):

In regards to opening a given page in a new tab: have you tried using a link control instead of a button? Set a computed target url (preferably under "All Properties >> data >> value") AND set the target property to "_blank" ("All Properties >> basics >> target")

Using css you can later on modify the link to look like a button, if that's needed.

*Btw:* in general there's no need to calculate the path if you stay within the same database; the XSPcontext sees the .nsf as a common root. Just have your url point to "/myNewPage.xsp" then add the query string accordingly, like

```
var url = "/" + xpage + "?action=openDocument&documentId="+ Action.claimDocID
```

Comment: Thanks Lothar, ended up using shillem's idea... Have used that in the past, but forgot about it. The page still errors on the first load though. Refreshing and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when universal ID provided to `documentId` URL parameter is invalid - possibly a document from another database or user has no access to it (readers field).

Comment: Hi Frantisek... The document ID is valid as after the initial window opening and receiving the error, click on page refresh and the page loads, so the URL is correct.

Comment: Provide full stack trace then.

Comment: Hi Frantisek... This hasn' happened for a while, but here's the stack  com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:529)    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148)    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100)    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:165)

Comment: BTW... I couldn't put in the full stack, too long. And, as I pointed out in my original comment, if I press reload on the URL that's sent, the page loads successfully.

Comment: That stacktrace should be in question (you can edit it), not the comment.

Comment: > if I press reload on the URL that's sent, the page loads successfully - my guess: you open datasource by some parameter, which is not evaluated correctly the first time page loads. next time the param is OK and page loads without errors. we can't help without more details about your page, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a link with a `target="_blank"` parameter:

```
<xp:link value="/my_page_name.xsp" text="to the infinity and beyond" target="_blank">
    <xp:this.parameters>
        <xp:parameter name="action" value="openDocument" />
        <xp:parameter name="documentId" value="#{Action.claimDocID}" />
    </xp:this.parameters>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: Thanks shillem... forgot all about doing that.. Have changed the code to use the above.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. In My Case I was remove field In Shared Elements. After Field was restored, error is disappear.